# Error: cvc-complex-type.4:Attribute 'bases-package' must appear on element 'neo4j:config'

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

If I add the following set of lines in `springContext.xml` file I am getting the `cvc-complex-type.4` error, how to solve this?

```
<bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestGraphDatabase">
    <constructor-arg value="http://localhost:7474/db/data/" />
</bean> 
<neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService" />
```

Please anybody help me on this.

Comment: <bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestGraphDatabase"> <constructor-arg value="http://localhost:7474/db/data/" /> </bean> <neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService" />

Comment: I think it's self-explanatory. Have a look at the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/3.1.0.RC1/reference/html/setup.html#d0e3716). `base-package` attribute needs to be in the xml config, the documentation explains its purpose.